# Assertion tab not visible in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I am running a test suite and need to add some assertion on response. But there is no button or tab to add it.

[image: Assertion Tab not visible]

Comment: i think ur using free version of SoapUI.

Comment: Can you select the Rest request and click on request message?

Comment: indeed, to have the possibility to see and use assertions, you have to select the request ...

Answer (score 1):

I also looking for Assertion functionality in SOAP UI but not found. But after searching in web I found that assertion functionality is now only available in SOAP UI Pro version.

http://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/assertion-teststep.html